# Browsing Main excel file and Save As directory path with use of Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have below Excel procedure I gather up and I am using it for couple of different calculations under different workbooks. So I was thinking instead changing the procedure for main and outcome files each time, I should be able to pick the file I want to carry out calculations in and the file path for outcomes files.

But I could not find anything for saving directory, I appreciate if you could help

```
Sub AsBuiltForm()

Dim SaveName As String
Dim mainBook As Workbook

a = InputBox("ENTER FIRST NUMBER ")
b = InputBox("ENTER LAST NUMBER ")

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\"  'main file can be browsed? 

Set mainBook = Excel.Workbooks("CP.xlsx")

    For i = a - 1 To b - 1

        mainBook.Sheets(1).Range("bi1") = i + 1
        SaveName = Sheets(1).Range("bi1").value & ".xlsx"

        mainBook.SaveCopyAs "C:\" & SaveName 'save directory?
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\" & SaveName 'save directory?

        With Excel.ActiveWorkbook
            .Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value
            .Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value
            Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
            .Sheets("il oufall").Delete

            .Sheets("1 of 2").Select
            Columns("Bh:BZ").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

            .Sheets("2 of 2").Select
            Columns("Bn:BZ").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

            .Close True

        End With

    Next

mainBook.Close False
Set mainBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.GetOpenFileName` to pick files that you want to open at Run-Time.

You can use the function below to browse for a folder where you wish to save a file.

```
Sub FindFolder()

Dim myFolder as String
myFolder = BrowseFolder("Pick a Folder Where to Save")

End Sub

Function BrowseFolder(Optional Caption As String, Optional InitialFolder As String) As String

' based on Browse For Folder from:
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BrowseFolder.aspx
' this functions requires that the following Reference is active:
    'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS As Long = &H1

Dim wsh As Object
Dim SH As Shell32.Shell
Dim F As Shell32.Folder

Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set SH = New Shell32.Shell
Set F = SH.BrowseForFolder(0&, Caption, BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS, InitialFolder)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
    If F = "Desktop" Then
        BrowseFolder = wsh.Specialfolders(F)
    Else
        BrowseFolder = F.Items.Item.path
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Would you elaborate or describe the use of the code as it does not seem to work somehow?

Comment: @serhat -> can you please tell how it is not working? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? If not, why is not working?

Comment: Sure first of all Application.GetOpenFileName is completely working out for picking the file i want to work with. Half the question is ok. But nothing missing with the first sub procedure for browsing folder to save files? because vba tries to understand browseFolder as variable. And second part starts with function part is totally greek to me.

Comment: @serhat -> Ha! at `totally greek to me` -> it was to me the first time too. Don't worry about fully understanding it. inside the VBE go to Tools>References and make sure Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation is checked. Then VBA will recognize BrowseFolder as a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not really an answer to your question, but a few tips to improve your code, and too long to add as a comment.

`Workbooks.Open` returns a `Workbook` object you can save the reference, so you don't have to rely on `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Dim oWorkbook As Workbook

Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\" & SaveName)

'***** Do something with oWorkbook
Debug.Print oWorkbook.FullName

Set oWorkbook = Nothing
```

A few other hints:

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module to force explicit declaration of all variables in order to find typos and other errors earlier.
- [Avoid selecting cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1490783)

Comment: Thank you for your time, i will keep all in mind in all attempts of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, browsing file works now; all the ins and outs aside, the problem i face with naming the file due to the variable "bi1" and saving as many loop as i asked for. I check several times before i bother you but i do not think i have the sufficient info to address "fn" as file in the use of Application.GetOpenFileName .

```
Option Explicit

Sub AsBuiltForm()

    Dim fn
    Dim myFolder As String
    Dim SaveName As String, a As Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer      

    myFolder = BrowseFolder("Pick a Folder Where to Save")

    MsgBox "Choose Calculation File "
     fn = Application.GetOpenFilename

Workbooks.Open fn                

    a = InputBox("ENTER FIRST NUMBER ")
    b = InputBox("ENTER LAST NUMBER ")        

For i = a - 1 To b - 1 Step 1

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn

    Range("bi1") = i + 1

    SaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("bi1").value

    Sheets(1).Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets(1).Range("A1:CT103").value

    Sheets(2).Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets(2).Range("A1:CT103").value

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myFolder & SaveName


    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    Next

End Sub  

Function BrowseFolder(Optional Caption As String, Optional InitialFolder As String) As String

' based on Browse For Folder from:
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BrowseFolder.aspx
' this functions requires that the following Reference is active:
    'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS As Long = &H1

Dim wsh As Object
Dim SH As Shell32.Shell
Dim F As Shell32.Folder

Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set SH = New Shell32.Shell
Set F = SH.BrowseForFolder(0&, Caption, BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS, InitialFolder)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
    If F = "Desktop" Then
        BrowseFolder = wsh.Specialfolders(F)
    Else
        BrowseFolder = F.Items.Item.Path
    End If
End If    
End Function
```